# What is the most secure way for storing user's passwords inside database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Which is the most secure and most efficient way for storing passwords inside the database tables using PHP?

So far I have used the `md5()` and the `sha256` algorithm for storing passwords where both of them can be easily hacked using rainbow tables if finally someone gain access on the database.

Comment: [password_hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) if you're on PHP >= 5.5.0, or [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) if on PHP >=5.3.7

Comment: While this is a "duplicate", **please follow the links here** as the new `password_*` API is the correct approach for a custom authentication store implementation - unless, perhaps, you're Bruce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bcrypt is usually considered the most secure option.

If you're using PHP 5.5 you can use the new password hashing API to make it easier to work with. There's a decent tutorial at [Hashing Passwords with the PHP 5.5 Password Hashing API](http://www.sitepoint.com/hashing-passwords-php-5-5-password-hashing-api/).

> Using bcrypt is the currently accepted best practice for hashing passwords, but a large number of developers still use older and weaker algorithms like MD5 and SHA1. Some developers don’t even use a salt while hashing. *The new hashing API in PHP 5.5 aims to draw attention towards bcrypt while hiding its complexity ..*

Comment: Someone needs to give you some rep and quick. That number isn't good! :)

Comment: But still do not forget that if you are not using for example SSL somebody can read your password "on the way"

Answer (score 3):

Using `bcrypt` with hash is currently the best thing to do using PHP.
**Don't** use `md5` or `sha1` functions, as they are older and weaker algorithms.

Since PHP 5.5, you can use the new `password_hash`, `password_verify`, `password_needs_rehash` and `password_get_info`. You can read more about the new hashing functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php):

> The password hashing API *[.. makes] it easy to create and manage passwords in a secure manner*.

also:

> This extension is available since PHP 5.5.0 but there is also an » userland implementation for PHP >= 5.3.7.

Comment: A userland implementation of password_hash is available for PHP >=5.3.7

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, fixed my comment (and thanks for the guy who added the quote). :)