# Successful inserted records in database but unrecognisable in the web system

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, insert

I have this problem with my web system. As administrator, my purpose is to register some  users giving them `username`,`password`,`firstname` and `lastname`. I do that properly since all the records are inserted correctly. But when I'm trying to have access as one of those users, I cannot enter, geting the message **"Username and password do not match"**. This is my login check code:

```
      if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; 
            if ((!$username) || (!$password)) {
                do_html_header('');

                echo '<h3 style="color:#800000;">Please fill in both fields</h3><br><br></br></br>';
                display_login_form();
            }       
            else {
            $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username="'.$_POST['username'].'" AND password=sha1("'.$_POST['password'].'")') or die(mysql_error());
            $login_check_member = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if($login_check_member > 0) {
                     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        $role = $row["role"];
                        $_SESSION['role'] = $role;
                    }
                }
                else { // Run this code if login_check is equal to 0 meaning they do not exist
                do_html_header('');

                echo '<h3 style="color:#800000;">The Username And Password do not match.</h3><br><br></br></br>';
                display_login_form();

                }
```

Apparently, there is a problem with my while loop. But it does work properly for those users inserted in my database via MySql console of wampserver. The problem exists only for the users inserted via the web site.
The part of code that I use to insert new users (servers) is :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$role = $_POST['role'];


$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db=mysql_select_db("buzzcafe" ,$conn);

 //$username= $_SESSION['username'];

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
 if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
  if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) { 
    if (isset($_POST['lastname'])) { 
        if(isset($_POST['role'])) {

        $insertServer = mysql_query("INSERT INTO servers (username,password,firstname,lastname,role) VALUES('".$username."',sha1('".$password."'),'".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$role."')")or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<h5 style=color:#800000><i>The server ".$username." is now registered </i></h5>";
                display_manager_menu();
            }

        }
    }
 }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: OT: You can give multiple arguments to `isset()`, it will check that they're all set. So you can replace all those nested `if`s with a single call.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is the `while` loop? The `if` statement doesn't go into the `while` loop if it displays the `do not match` message.

Comment: Your INSERT is into `servers`; the SELECT is from `members`

Comment: Maybe try trimming the password before calling `SHA1()` on it.

Comment: @andrewsi That must be a copy error, do you think the `servers` table really has a `firstname` column?

Comment: @Barmar - I've seen enough code on SO that it's entirely possible :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Look at the table you `INSERT` the data ('servers'). It's different from the table you `SELECT` the data from ('members').
2. Don't use the `mysql_query` function, as it deprecated. Try using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead.
3. Don't **ever** use unfiltered input in your query.
4. Try using more secure functions for your login/registration form (like bcrypt, or password_hash). Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083582/what-is-the-most-secure-way-for-storing-users-passwords-inside-database-using-p/19083638#19083638).

Comment: Oh my Gosh! After all these hours, I probably need some rest. Thanks to you I've just realised that I was not inserting the records into the table from which I had to select them from. Thanks a lot for that.